# Cargar una imagen mientras ejecuto un Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, web

Buenas, tengo un envío POST a través de Ajax y mientras carga en el div escribo una frase de espera, sin embargo quiero cargar por una imagen (un gif si fuera posible).

¿Cuál sería la manera más sencilla de hacerlo? Gracias

```
 $.ajax({
            data:  {lat:lat,long:long,termidventa:termidventa,termidservicio:termidservicio, termname:termname, pventa:pventa, postventa:postventa}, 

            url:   '/wp-content/themes/starkers-html5-master/mostrar_paises.php', 
            type:  'post', 
            beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#caja21").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
            },
            success:  function (response) { 

                    $("#caja21").html(response);
            }
    });
```

Comment: No cargues la imagen. La imagen ya esta alli. Solo hazla visible antes de llamar al ajax (Show) y ocultala en el success o fail (hide).

Comment: Podrias insertar codigo html cargando la imagen, o mostrando y ocultando un div mientras carga...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta mostrando la imagen antes de realizar el ajax y luego al finalizar, la ocultas.

Por ejemplo:

```js
$("#cargando").show();
$("#listo").hide();
$.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",function(post){
  for(var i = 0;i<post.length;i++)
  {
    $("#posts").append("<li><p>" + post[i].email + "</p>" + post[i].body + "</li>");
    
     $("#cargando").hide();
    $("#listo").show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cargando">
  <img
    width="200"
   src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" />
  <p>
    Cargando contenido
  </p>
</div>
<div id="contenido">
   <ul id="posts">
   </ul>
</div>
```

Fijate como muestra la imagen y despues de cargar el contenido, lo oculta.

Answer (score 0):

No cargues la imagen. La imagen ya esta alli. Solo hazla visible antes de llamar al ajax (Show) y ocultala en el success o fail (hide).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#carga").hide();
});

function enviar(){
  $("#carga").show();
  $.ajax({
    url:   'https://httpbin.org/get', 
    type:  'get', 
    success:  function () { 
      $("#carga").hide();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="carga" src="https://media1.tenor.com/images/83f824de4a72d3334ecb875e1ea894dd/tenor.gif?itemid=5521433" />
<button onclick="enviar()">ENVIAR</button>
```